# Access RestKit request body

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I can't find where is the body of my request? In what property?

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:object 
                                       path:path 
                                 parameters:parameters 
                                    success:success
                                    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"???");
}
```

Now how to print whole body of request? I'd like to see the path with header and parameters.

Comment: have you tried `object` ?

Comment: @Avdept `object` is data, which I want to save via post method.

Comment: Why, what are you trying to achieve. Trace log or Charles are best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to see output of everything via setting:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network*", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Body of your request is in `object`, as it is specified here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#post-patch-and-delete-an-object

If you want to log your requests and responses you can use [AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger).